# Google Chrome and Chromium, "Aw, Snap" under all conditions.... how to isolate reason

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

I have been using Google Chrome on my Slackware unix box for about 6 months now.  So I know the program *does* work on Slackware.  But -- I recently had to recompile and upgrade my linux kernel from 3.17.8 to 3.18.9 in order to upgrade the system's ATI R9 290 graphics card behavior for games, and I also did it in hopes of eliminating a google-chrome ERROR start up message which says "ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(325)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process" , BUT shortly afterward I started getting the Aw, Snap! blue screen of death and can no longer web browse.

I tried all the obvious repair tricks, deleting the google ~/.cache/... and ~/.config/..., reinstalling chrome (and got & compiled the latest releases google-chrome-41.0.2272.101-x86_64-1,  chromium-41.0.2272.101-x86_64-1alien, ), to the extreme attempt in desperation of completely re-installing Slackware linux from scratch on a new hard drive assuming I must have damaged a library or something somewhere and even recompiling the kernel both with and without seccomp trusted byte code, and switching back and forth between mozilla-nss-3.15.2-x86_64-2, and seamonkey-solibs-2.21-x86_64-1  to see if either library set caused a problem...

And just to be safe, I installed all the 32 bit multilib compatability libraries for *every* 64 bit package I installed, and added the following non-standard libraries to the system which some websites suggested might have been needed in the past for Chrome, even if they aren't anymore...

```
ORBit2-2.14.19-x86_64-1_SBo
GConf-3.2.6-x86_64-1
pciutils-3.2.0-x86_64-2  # To fix slackware libpci.a not being a dynamic lib.
libgnome-keyring-3.8.0-x86_64-1
gnome-keyring-3.8.2-x86_64-1
freealut-1.1.0-x86_64-1ponce
freeglut-2.8.0-x86_64-1
OpenAL-1.16.0-x86_64-1_SBo
```

And for fonts, I have true microsoft windows Times, and Arial, and also dejavu-fonts-ttf-2.34-noarch-1, and fslsfonts-1.0.4-x86_64-1, which have always been sufficient in the past, but to be safe I added liberation-fonts-ttf-1.07.2-noarch-1 recently; but it didn't help.

The present ldd of chromium shows the following libraries, all of them being stock for slackware64 14.1 except the ones listed above; As you can see, there are NO missing libraries.

```
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff60fda000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x00007f8a60296000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f8a60091000)
    libgobject-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libgobject-2.0.so.0(0x00007f8a5fe42000)
    libglib-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f8a5fb18000)
    libnss3.so => /usr/lib64/libnss3.so (0x00007f8a5f7db000)
    libsmime3.so => /usr/lib64/libsmime3.so (0x00007f8a5f5ae000)
    libnssutil3.so => /usr/lib64/libnssutil3.so (0x00007f8a5f383000)
    libplc4.so => /usr/lib64/libplc4.so (0x00007f8a5f17e000)
    libnspr4.so => /usr/lib64/libnspr4.so (0x00007f8a5ef41000)
    libgio-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libgio-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f8a5ebe8000)
    libfontconfig.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libfontconfig.so.1 (0x00007f8a5e9ad000)
    libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libfreetype.so.6 (0x00007f8a5e71c000)
    libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f8a5e510000)
    libcairo.so.2 => /usr/lib64/libcairo.so.2 (0x00007f8a5e21b000)
    libpango-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libpango-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f8a5dfd1000)
    libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libX11.so.6 (0x00007f8a5dc97000)
    libXi.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libXi.so.6 (0x00007f8a5da87000)
    libXcursor.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libXcursor.so.1 (0x00007f8a5d87d000)
    libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libXext.so.6 (0x00007f8a5d66c000)
    libXfixes.so.3 => /usr/lib64/libXfixes.so.3 (0x00007f8a5d466000)
    libXrender.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libXrender.so.1 (0x00007f8a5d25d000)
    libXcomposite.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libXcomposite.so.1 (0x00007f8a5d05b000)
    libasound.so.2 => /usr/lib64/libasound.so.2 (0x00007f8a5cd65000)
    libXdamage.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libXdamage.so.1 (0x00007f8a5cb63000)
    libXtst.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libXtst.so.6 (0x00007f8a5c95e000)
    libXrandr.so.2 => /usr/lib64/libXrandr.so.2 (0x00007f8a5c754000)
    libexpat.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007f8a5c52b000)
    libcups.so.2 => /usr/lib64/libcups.so.2 (0x00007f8a5c2e0000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f8a5c0c2000)
    libdbus-1.so.3 => /usr/lib64/libdbus-1.so.3 (0x00007f8a5be7c000)
    libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f8a5b848000)
    libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f8a5b595000)
    libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f8a5b375000)
    libXss.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libXss.so.1 (0x00007f8a5b172000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f8a5ae6f000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f8a5ab6d000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f8a5a957000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f8a5a58d000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f8a679db000)
    libffi.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libffi.so.6 (0x00007f8a5a385000)
    libplds4.so => /usr/lib64/libplds4.so (0x00007f8a5a182000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib64/libz.so.1 (0x00007f8a59f6c000)
    libgmodule-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libgmodule-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f8a59d69000)
    libresolv.so.2 => /lib64/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007f8a59b4e000)
    libbz2.so.1 => /lib64/libbz2.so.1 (0x00007f8a5993e000)
    libpng14.so.14 => /usr/lib64/libpng14.so.14 (0x00007f8a59719000)
    libpixman-1.so.0 => /usr/lib64/../lib64/libpixman-1.so.0 (0x00007f8a59470000)
    libxcb-shm.so.0 => /usr/lib64/../lib64/libxcb-shm.so.0 (0x00007f8a5926e000)
    libX11-xcb.so.1 => /usr/lib64/../lib64/libX11-xcb.so.1 (0x00007f8a5906d000)
    libxcb-render.so.0 => /usr/lib64/../lib64/libxcb-render.so.0 (0x00007f8a58e63000)
    libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib64/../lib64/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007f8a58c46000)
    libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib64/../lib64/libXau.so.6 (0x00007f8a58a43000)
    libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib64/../lib64/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007f8a5883d000)
    libpangoft2-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib64/../lib64/libpangoft2-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f8a58629000)
    libgthread-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib64/../lib64/libgthread-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f8a58428000)
    libharfbuzz.so.0 => /usr/lib64/../lib64/libharfbuzz.so.0 (0x00007f8a58196000)
    libicule.so.51 => /usr/lib64/../lib64/libicule.so.51 (0x00007f8a57f40000)
    libicuuc.so.51 => /usr/lib64/../lib64/libicuuc.so.51 (0x00007f8a57bd6000)
    libicudata.so.51 => /usr/lib64/../lib64/libicudata.so.51 (0x00007f8a5648b000)
    libssl.so.1 => /lib64/libssl.so.1 (0x00007f8a56220000)
    libcrypto.so.1 => /lib64/libcrypto.so.1 (0x00007f8a55e47000)
    libcrypt.so.1 => /lib64/libcrypt.so.1 (0x00007f8a55c0e000)
    libXinerama.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libXinerama.so.1 (0x00007f8a55a0b000)
    libatk-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libatk-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f8a557e8000)
```

But -- it's all no good.  Both chrome and chromium (which I can successfully compile from scratch without any problems), give the same blue screen of death with "Aw, Snap!" at start-up, and neither will even allow the display of the "about chrome page" or anything else.  It's is 100% unable to display anything except popup dialogs.  Please note:  Firefox, several OpenGL games, and even GPU accerated ones like Trine,  and *all* other normal slackware X11 applications work perfectly.  There is no firewall, or ad-blocking, or anything installed on this system at the moment.  Yet -- the problem persists.

I decided to enable the error reporting feature of chrome to let them know but that merely caused a list of error messages to scroll by in the terminal saying that the certificate of authority of google could not be verified locally...  Which made me laugh, and decide to post here -- for Google probably believes there is nothing wrong with their browser under linux -- because they aren't receiveing any error messages... and never will...

So, how can I isolate what is causing the problem?  (Or at very least get bug reporting working?!)  I'm willing to try on chrome or chromium .

For my last attempt before giving up, on chromium, I tried assuming it was a gpu-related problem, and perhaps a kernel setting messed it up -- so I looked for clues on how to turn off the gpu completely.

I can not tell if these flags are specific to chrome, or if they will work with chrome and chromium both, but here's what I did from the command line:

chromium --disable-accelerated-composting --disable-accelerated-layers --disable-accelerated-2d-canvas --blacklist-webgl --blacklist-accelerated-composting --enable-logging=stderr --v=1 www.yahoo.com  2> ~/chrome_err.log

However, that didn't even get rid of the original error message that made me want to upgrade in the first place, for it still reports ERROR: multiple threads for gpu.

chrome_err.log:

```
[1725:1725:0324/120300:VERBOSE1:breakpad_linux.cc(1659)] Breakpad disabled
[1:1:0324/120300:VERBOSE1:zygote_main_linux.cc(600)] ZygoteMain: initializing 2 fork delegates
[1:1:0324/120300:VERBOSE1:nacl_fork_delegate_linux.cc(142)] NaClForkDelegate::Init()
[1:1:0324/120300:VERBOSE1:nacl_fork_delegate_linux.cc(142)] NaClForkDelegate::Init()
[1725:1748:0324/120300:VERBOSE1:google_api_keys.cc(237)] Using default value "726124521725-usiuc172onlf7t4ind7sf2detm950t7n.apps.googleusercontent.com" for API key GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID_MAIN
[1725:1748:0324/120300:VERBOSE1:google_api_keys.cc(237)] Using default value "ll1NK5GBOrAUb6zSbcgAX1Q7" for API key GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET_MAIN
[1725:1748:0324/120300:VERBOSE1:google_api_keys.cc(237)] Using default value "726124521725-usiuc172onlf7t4ind7sf2detm950t7n.apps.googleusercontent.com" for API key GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID_CLOUD_PRINT
[1725:1748:0324/120300:VERBOSE1:google_api_keys.cc(237)] Using default value "ll1NK5GBOrAUb6zSbcgAX1Q7" for API key GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET_CLOUD_PRINT
[1725:1748:0324/120300:VERBOSE1:google_api_keys.cc(237)] Using default value "726124521725-usiuc172onlf7t4ind7sf2detm950t7n.apps.googleusercontent.com" for API key GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID_REMOTING
[1725:1748:0324/120300:VERBOSE1:google_api_keys.cc(237)] Using default value "ll1NK5GBOrAUb6zSbcgAX1Q7" for API key GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET_REMOTING
[1725:1748:0324/120300:VERBOSE1:google_api_keys.cc(237)] Using default value "726124521725-usiuc172onlf7t4ind7sf2detm950t7n.apps.googleusercontent.com" for API key GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID_REMOTING_HOST
[1725:1748:0324/120300:VERBOSE1:google_api_keys.cc(237)] Using default value "ll1NK5GBOrAUb6zSbcgAX1Q7" for API key GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET_REMOTING_HOST
[1725:1725:0324/120300:VERBOSE1:pref_proxy_config_tracker_impl.cc(148)] 0x7fef8a158280: set chrome proxy config service to 0x7fef8a1899f0
[1725:1725:0324/120300:VERBOSE1:pref_proxy_config_tracker_impl.cc(277)] 0x7fef8a158280: Done pushing proxy to UpdateProxyConfig
[1725:1725:0324/120300:VERBOSE1:app_list_syncable_service_factory.cc(55)] AppListSyncableServiceFactory()
[1725:1748:0324/120300:VERBOSE1:multi_log_ct_verifier.cc(76)] Adding CT log: Google 'Pilot' log
[1725:1748:0324/120300:VERBOSE1:multi_log_ct_verifier.cc(76)] Adding CT log: Google 'Aviator' log
[1725:1748:0324/120300:VERBOSE1:multi_log_ct_verifier.cc(76)] Adding CT log: DigiCert Log Server
 [1725:1725:0324/120300:VERBOSE1:bluetooth_low_energy_event_router.cc(192)] Initializing BluetoothLowEnergyEventRouter.
[1725:1725:0324/120300:VERBOSE1:bluetooth_low_energy_event_router.cc(195)] Bluetooth not supported on the current platform.
[1725:1725:0324/120300:VERBOSE1:app_list_syncable_service_factory.cc(45)] BuildInstanceFor: Default (0x7fef8a19bde0)
[1725:1725:0324/120300:VERBOSE1:pref_proxy_config_tracker_impl.cc(148)] 0x7fef8a287cb0: set chrome proxy config service to 0x7fef8a288370
[1725:1725:0324/120300:VERBOSE1:pref_proxy_config_tracker_impl.cc(277)] 0x7fef8a287cb0: Done pushing proxy to UpdateProxyConfig
[1725:1725:0324/120300:VERBOSE1:extension_service.cc(1533)] AddComponentExtension Bookmark Manager
[1725:1725:0324/120300:VERBOSE1:extension_service.cc(1533)] AddComponentExtension Cloud Print
[1725:1725:0324/120300:VERBOSE1:extension_service.cc(1533)] AddComponentExtension Web Store
[1725:1725:0324/120300:VERBOSE1:extension_service.cc(1533)] AddComponentExtension Chromium
[1725:1725:0324/120300:VERBOSE1:extension_service.cc(1533)] AddComponentExtension Settings
[1725:1725:0324/120300:VERBOSE1:extension_service.cc(1533)] AddComponentExtension Google Now
[1725:1725:0324/120300:VERBOSE1:extension_service.cc(1533)] AddComponentExtension CryptoTokenExtension
[1725:1725:0324/120300:VERBOSE1:app_list_syncable_service.cc(284)] 0x7fef8a26c8c0: AppListSyncableService: InitializeWithService.
[1725:1725:0324/120300:VERBOSE1:app_list_syncable_service.cc(837)] 0x7fef8a26c8c0: SyncStarted: Flare.
[1725:1725:0324/120300:WARNING:data_reduction_proxy_settings.cc(365)] SPDY proxy OFF at startup
[1725:1725:0324/120300:VERBOSE1:account_reconcilor.cc(70)] AccountReconcilor::AccountReconcilor
[1725:1725:0324/120300:VERBOSE1:account_reconcilor.cc(80)] AccountReconcilor::Initialize
[1725:1725:0324/120300:VERBOSE1:ev_whitelist_component_installer.cc(182)] Registering EV whitelist component.
[1725:1725:0324/120300:VERBOSE1:component_updater_service.cc(267)] CrxUpdateService starting up
[1725:1764:0324/120300:VERBOSE1:ev_whitelist_component_installer.cc(68)] Initial load: reading EV whitelist from file: /home/andrew3/.config/chromium/ev_hashes_whitelist.bin
[1725:1725:0324/120300:VERBOSE1:startup_browser_creator_impl.cc(587)] StartupBrowserCreatorImpl::ProcessStartupURLs
[1725:1751:0324/120300:VERBOSE1:ev_whitelist_component_installer.cc(147)] Verifying install: /home/andrew3/.config/chromium/EVWhitelist/6/_platform_specific/all/ev_hashes_whitelist.bin
[1725:1725:0324/120300:VERBOSE1:startup_browser_creator_impl.cc(595)] Pref: default
[1725:1764:0324/120300:VERBOSE1:packed_ct_ev_whitelist.cc(62)] Uncompressing EV whitelist of size 1113849
[1725:1751:0324/120300:VERBOSE1:ev_whitelist_component_installer.cc(159)] Whitelist size: 1113849
[1725:1744:0324/120300:VERBOSE1:crl_set_fetcher.cc(103)] Loaded 201209 bytes of CRL set from disk
[1725:1748:0324/120300:VERBOSE1:crl_set_fetcher.cc(125)] Installed CRL set #2146
[1725:1725:0324/120300:VERBOSE1:password_store_factory.cc(207)] Password storage detected desktop environment: (unknown)
[1725:1725:0324/120300:WARNING:password_store_factory.cc(237)] Using basic (unencrypted) store for password storage. See http://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/LinuxPasswordStorage for more information about password storage options.
[7:7:0324/120300:VERBOSE1:sandbox_linux.cc(64)] Activated seccomp-bpf sandbox for process type: renderer.
[7:7:0324/120300:VERBOSE1:child_thread.cc(245)] Mojo is disabled on child
[1725:1725:0324/120300:VERBOSE1:component_updater_service.cc(267)] CrxUpdateService starting up
[1725:1725:0324/120300:VERBOSE1:component_updater_service.cc(274)] First update attempt will take place in 360 seconds
[1725:1725:0324/120300:VERBOSE1:ev_whitelist_component_installer.cc(134)] Component ready, version 6 in /home/andrew3/.config/chromium/EVWhitelist/6
[1725:1742:0324/120300:VERBOSE1:ev_whitelist_component_installer.cc(36)] Reading new EV whitelist from file: /home/andrew3/.config/chromium/EVWhitelist/6/_platform_specific/all/ev_hashes_whitelist.bin
[1725:1764:0324/120300:VERBOSE1:ev_whitelist_component_installer.cc(88)] EV whitelist: Sucessfully loaded initial data.
[1725:1748:0324/120300:VERBOSE1:packed_ct_ev_whitelist.cc(26)] Setting new EV Certs whitelist.
[1725:1742:0324/120300:VERBOSE1:packed_ct_ev_whitelist.cc(62)] Uncompressing EV whitelist of size 1113849
[1725:1748:0324/120300:VERBOSE1:packed_ct_ev_whitelist.cc(26)] Setting new EV Certs whitelist.
[1754:1754:0324/120300:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(325)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process
[1754:1754:0324/120300:VERBOSE1:child_thread.cc(245)] Mojo is disabled on child
[12:12:0324/120300:VERBOSE1:sandbox_linux.cc(64)] Activated seccomp-bpf sandbox for process type: utility.
[12:12:0324/120300:VERBOSE1:child_thread.cc(245)] Mojo is disabled on child
[1725:1725:0324/120302:VERBOSE1:account_reconcilor.cc(98)] AccountReconcilor::Shutdown
[1725:1725:0324/120302:VERBOSE1:merge_session_helper.cc(212)] MergeSessionHelper::CancelAll
[1725:1725:0324/120302:VERBOSE1:account_reconcilor.cc(74)] AccountReconcilor::~AccountReconcilor
[1725:1725:0324/120302:VERBOSE1:ipc_sync_channel.cc(386)] Canceling pending sends
[1725:1725:0324/120302:VERBOSE1:component_updater_service.cc(286)] CrxUpdateService stopping
[1725:1727:0324/120302:VERBOSE1:sandbox_ipc_linux.cc(122)] SandboxIPCHandler stopping.

....  [Edit: Note -- I'm appending what happens when I manually type in a web page name, below]

[12:12:0324/121659:VERBOSE1:sandbox_linux.cc(64)] Activated seccomp-bpf sandbox for process type: utility.
[12:12:0324/121659:VERBOSE1:child_thread.cc(245)] Mojo is disabled on child
[14:14:0324/121702:VERBOSE1:sandbox_linux.cc(64)] Activated seccomp-bpf sandbox for process type: renderer.
[14:14:0324/121702:VERBOSE1:child_thread.cc(245)] Mojo is disabled on child
[1839:1862:0324/121702:VERBOSE1:resource_loader.cc(241)] OnReceivedRedirect: http://www.yahoo.com/
[1868:1915:0324/121702:VERBOSE1:ipc_sync_channel.cc(386)] Canceling pending sends
[1868:1868:0324/121702:VERBOSE1:ipc_sync_channel.cc(386)] Canceling pending sends
[1868:1915:0324/121702:VERBOSE1:ipc_sync_channel.cc(386)] Canceling pending sends
[1839:1839:0324/121705:VERBOSE1:account_reconcilor.cc(98)] AccountReconcilor::Shutdown
[1839:1839:0324/121705:VERBOSE1:merge_session_helper.cc(212)] MergeSessionHelper::CancelAll
[1839:1839:0324/121705:VERBOSE1:account_reconcilor.cc(74)] AccountReconcilor::~AccountReconcilor
[1839:1839:0324/121705:VERBOSE1:ipc_sync_channel.cc(386)] Canceling pending sends
[1839:1839:0324/121705:VERBOSE1:component_updater_service.cc(286)] CrxUpdateService stopping

****Edit: Note ... histograms would normally follow, but I truncated it.
```

So, anyone have an idea of how to figure out and repair the problem ?
I've never had bluetooth, so I don't think installing those libs will help.
But I am stumped and frustrated, there's no obvious error message clue as to what might be causing the problem, just some esoteric mention of "mojo" diabling without indication of whether that's even good or bad, and the fact that just about everything is shutting down and cancelling everything.... for no reason...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem.
Running DMESG, I found a warning that an instruction exception had happened from Google Chrome.  That's how I was able to figure out that the kernel processor configuration had somehow changed the memory management algorithms during my recompile.

I am using kernel 3.18.25, and I think it was specifically the "Processor Type and features -> Transparent Hugepage Suport" that caused the problem. Hugepage support must be set to "madvise" rather than to "always" in order for Chrome to work.  I suspect the reason Chrome fails, is that the kernel call fails even though the memory is allocated when it is set to always.  Some other people on the web reported a similar issue in obscure Google forums lists, so I'm just confirming that it is the most likely culprit.

Just in case that is not the only option which caused Google Chrome to fail, here are the kernel options which I tinkered with between the time I discovered the AW snap problem, and when the problem was solved.
I am listing only the options that I turned on, or changed the value of in that period of time.  The rest of the unlisted options that deal with memory management, are all "off".

Processor Types and Features -> Linux guest support: (enable)
Enable paravirtualization, Paravirtualization layer for spinlocks, Xen guest support, Support for running as PVH guest, KVM Guest support, Paravirtualization steal time accounting.

Processor Types and Features -> Support Intel Processors, Support AMD processor

Processor Types and Features:
Enable 1GB pages for kernel pagetables.
Numa Memory allocation and Scheduler support:
 ACPI NUMA detection (only),
6 (Maximum Numa nodes as a power of 2), 
Sparse Memory virtual memmap, 
Enable to assign a node which has only movable memory, 
enable for balloon memory compaction, 
page migration, 
Enable KSM for page merging, 
(4096) Low address space protect from user allocation, 
Transparent Hugepage support (madvise), 
Continuguous memory allocator,
(7) maximum count of the CMA areas,
MTRR support, cleanup support,
MTRR cleanup enable value (1),
MTRR cleanup spare reg num (1),
Enable seccompt to safely compute untrusted byte code.

Answer (score -2):

Try to start it as chromium `--no-sandbox` - worked for me (but then I guess my kernel somewhat misconfigured)